# Photoshop CS5 Contact Sheet II abnormalities

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, flatten

I'm using Photoshop CS5 on multiple computers, each with their own individual licenses and when I tried to use the File >> Automate >> Contact Sheet II, the outcome of the feature varies.

On one PC, the final output is flattened, while on another PC the output is in combination of raster layers and text layers (unflattened).

***I want my Contact Sheet II output to be in layers (i.e unflattened) but I can't seem to find a way to activate this feature (on the PC where the output is flattened).***

Answer (score 1):

On the problem machine, try resetting the Photoshop preferences. (Double-click the PS icon to open the program, then immediately hold down Ctl, Alt and Shift until you get the "Delete Preferences" dialog, then click OK.)

It's a long time since I've used any of the legacy plug-ins, far less and the sadly-deceased InDesign contact sheet script replaced Contact Sheet II as soon as it made its all-too-brief appearance in Bridge. The Output module in no way substitutes for either one, unfortunately.

Here's a suggestion: download XBytor's fantastic ContactSheetX, which you can find [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ps-scripts/files/) on SourceForge.net. The latest version is dated Feb 2011, a tad more recent than the obsolescent Adobe script, and is a great Open Source resource.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Flatten All Layers":

[image]

Worked for me with Photoshop 23.5.1.